# Bookmark Saving Database Design

Tags: database, tags, schema, bookmarks

I am trying to come up with a database design that will be suitable for users to be able to save bookmarks along with tags (different tags for different users).

I'm also pretty unsure how I am going to let users have different titles for the same bookmark. Any good way of doing this?

This is what I have so far:

```
Bookmark {
    BookmarkID
    Title
    URL
    Source
}

BookmarkSaves {
    BookmarkID
    UserID
}

Tag {
    TagID
    Title
}

BookmarkTag {
    BookmarkID
    TagID
    UserID
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm also pretty unsure how I am going to let users have different titles for the same bookmark.

You do so by making the title part of your BookmarkSaves table.

Comment: I'm planning on have a most popular list, how would I know which title to display though?

Comment: I have the feeling that would be way to many queries resulting in poor site performance.

Comment: Of course not. Keep the title field in Bookmarks, add a dirty flag/bit, and add a cron to materialize the most popular title on a daily basis.

Comment: Add a bit field called dirty. On insert/delete/update of BookmarkSave, `update Bookmark set dirty = 1 where bookmarkId = :id and dirty = 0`. Then run a daily cron, compile updated statistics the dirty rows, and mark them as clean as you do...